# Show only one child of expandable list at a time

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter

Is it possible to only expand one child of an `ExpandableListView` at a time, thus opening a second child would close the previously opened child?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

I'm not aware of any automatic methods for this, but you can implement `ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener`, in where you run `collapseGroup()` for all list groups except the one being clicked. This will do what you want.

Comment: Better yet, use the `ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener` class. Also, you can keep track of the last expanded group, and collapse it when the next one is expanded (to prevent calling `collapseGroup()` on an arbitrarily  large number of list items.

Comment: Thanks guys, I will try out your suggestions tonight!

Comment: Just wanted to follow up that this suggestion worked perfectly, I just keep track of the last expanded group and close it before expanding the next group to be expanded! Thanks bos & Jason!

Answer (score 142):

Just to confirm bos's answer in code:

```
    expandableList.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {
        int previousGroup = -1;

        @Override
        public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
            if(groupPosition != previousGroup)
                expandableList.collapseGroup(previousGroup);
            previousGroup = groupPosition;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Perfect one. Thank you

Comment: can we get group view when user group expand event fire

Comment: Shoudn't "int previousGroup = -1" be "int previousGroup = 0" ?

Comment: @Ahsan no because `0` is a valid position in the list, so when you start you there is no "previous group" therefore -1 is correct and 0 would be incorrect

Comment: Perfect answer. Thanks mate. Also, I have a concern, while expanding particular group, the view automatically scrolls to the last child of the expanded group... How to make the scrollstate to be on the group instead of child? 

What happens is, if the child has more than 10+ records and it goes beyond the mobile height and screen scroll down to the last child pos. @Blundell need your assistance

Comment: Hello Everyone,This scroll expandablelistview scroll to bottom,how can I stop expandablelistview  to scroll bottom.
 I tried android:transcriptMode="disabled" but not works for me any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Also you can simple use the `withOnlyOneExpandedItem()` which is in FastAdapter

that is in [FastAdapter External Library](https://github.com/sathishmscict/FastAdapter) by mikepenz

For example as I am using it in my Drawer

```
drawer.getAdapter().withOnlyOneExpandedItem(true);
```

Comment: As I know there is no such method in ExpandableListVeiw.

Comment: sorry, I forgot that the source code I was reading is for an external library, also here it's link if are interested in it https://github.com/sathishmscict/FastAdapter/blob/master/library/src/main/java/com/mikepenz/fastadapter/FastAdapter.java

Answer (score -5):

you can use this for various conditions as you want to do in expansion of list -

```
      expList.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() 
        {
         @Override
         public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
           int childGroupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

        // Log.e("OnChildClickListener", "OK "+childGroupPosition+"  "+childPosition);javainterviewquestion
             if(childGroupPosition ==0 && childPosition == 0)
             {

             }
             if(childGroupPosition ==0 && childPosition == 1)
             {

             } 

          return false; 
         }
        });
```