# ExpandableListview - How do I close the previous opened item, when another item is clicked?

Tags: android, expandablelistview

How do I close the previous opened item, when another item is clicked on the expandablelistview?

I refer to this tutorial http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/android-expandable-list-view-tutorial/.
But when i click new item, prevoius item won't close.

Comment: Dear! be more detailed while questing.

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7862396/show-only-one-child-of-expandable-list-at-a-time

Answer (score 10, accepted):

So you need only one (or zero) expanded group at a time. Right? The following code will close the previously expanded group when you expand another one. Try it.

Here you go

```
final int[] prevExpandPosition = {-1};
    expandableListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
            if (prevExpandPosition[0] >= 0 && prevExpandPosition[0] != groupPosition) {
                expandableListView.collapseGroup(prevExpandPosition[0]);
            }
            prevExpandPosition[0] = groupPosition;
        }
    });
```

Comment: Glad that worked. You can always accept the answer by clicking the tick mark. Happy coding :)

Comment: Have a bug if want click at the same position two times.

Comment: @IbrahimSušić Edited. How's now?

Comment: expandableListView.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {
            int previousGroup = -1;

            @Override
            public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
                if(groupPosition != previousGroup)
                    expandableListView.collapseGroup(previousGroup);
                previousGroup = groupPosition;
            }
        }) ;

Answer (score 2):

You can implement `ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener`, in where you have to call`collapseGroup()` for all list groups except the one being clicked like this :

```
  expandableList.setOnGroupExpandListener(new OnGroupExpandListener() {
    int previousGroup = -1;

    @Override
    public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
        if(groupPosition != previousGroup)
            expandableList.collapseGroup(previousGroup);
        previousGroup = groupPosition;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        expandableList.setOnGroupExpandListener(new ExpandableListView.OnGroupExpandListener() {
        int previousGroup = -1;

        @Override
        public void onGroupExpand(int groupPosition) {
            if(groupPosition != previousGroup)
                expandableList.collapseGroup(previousGroup);
            previousGroup = groupPosition;
        }
    });
```